# How to Send and Receive Data(0x04,0x02,0x00,0x03B) in Android BLE ?

Tags: java, android, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can some one please help data sending using Bluetooth characteristic in Android BLE in below example format

I need to send data to BLE Other Device - 0x02, 0x04,0x00,0x0A etc.

And need to receive in same format from BLE device - 0x09,0x02 etc.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Regards,
Pravin

Comment: Where is the problem exactly? There are commands like BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic() to do so, but I assume your problem starts earlier than that?

Answer (score -1):

Yup, I got it. in Byte [] I can send data and receive it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Admittedly, there is no real question to answer here.